# Get id of an element by js in a module item

Tags: javascript, document-id, module

I don't know if i choose the correct title.

Here's my probleme, I've created a module in wich I can put my js/css (http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/586674moduleJs.png) and I would like to get the id of my html elements. Sharepoint is adding some kind of matrix characters to my elements ID's and each of them look similar to this : `ctl40_g_fa43dd10_b395_40e7_98cd_a52585a208c5_Timesheet`

So i used to get the id in my webpart using The CliendID of my item. Here's an example of what I was doing before moving my js to a separate file. (I was doing js/style in the webpart acsx file but i got some issues and i had to move my js/style in a separate folder).

js

```
$("#<%#Timesheet.ClientID%>").find("tbody").find("tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("data-name") == "timesheetEntryTotal") {
            $(this).before(tr);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

css

```
#<%#Timesheet.ClientID%> > tbody > tr > td {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

But now that I moved my js/css to a separate folder I can't user <%...%> anymore. So how I can get the ID of my elements now?

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution is to use the HTML5 custom attribute like data-name.

So instead of getting the id like this `$("#<%#Timesheet.ClientId%>")`, I now do `$("table[data-id='Timesheet']")`

Same thing for the css selector.

```
table[data-id="Timesheet"] > tbody > tr > td {
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery to select element, you could use '$' for ends with.

```
$("table[id$='Timesheet']")
```

You could do similar for CSS:

```
table[id$="Timesheet"] > tbody > tr > td {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, it would probably work too. I'm learning things on the job so i'm not aware of everything. Thanks.